# Как останавить telegram бота (aiogram) при любой ошибке?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

**Telegram бот** написан на **python** при помощи библиотеки **aiogram**. Есть необходимость **останавливать** самого бота и **закрывать** программу при возникновении ошибок, которые касаются непосредственно **библиотеки aiogram**.

***В качестве примера ошибки можно рассмотреть*** *(
или любую другую которая возникает внутри библиотеки aiogram)*:

`aiogram.utils.exceptions.TerminatedByOtherGetUpdates: Terminated by other getupdates request; make sure that only one bot instance is running`

Если вкратце вот код:

```py
from aiogram import Bot, types
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.utils import executor
from config import TOKEN


if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot = Bot(token=TOKEN)
    dp = Dispatcher(bot)

    executor.start_polling(dp)
```

Пробовал оборачивать `executor.start_polling(dp)` в конструкцию `try, except`. **Однако** это не помогло ибо ошибка возникала внутри `executor.start_polling(dp)` и тем самым не имела никакого влияния на `try, except` главной функции.

**Что необходимо сделать для остановки бота в случаем ошибки и закрытием самой программы?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Вы должны понимать, что говоря уже о любой ошибке можно говорить и о
> 100 ошибках возникших при работе с aiogram, так как никто не знает на
> сколько вы правильно пишите код и никто не знает с какой ошибкой вы
> можете столкнуться в процессе работы с библиотекой, поэтому если вы
> хотите обрабатывать все ошибки, читайте моё краткое руководство, которое я написал ниже.

> Первым делом вам необходимо найти файл `exceptions.py` в папке `utils` с `aiogram`, сделать это можно просто, к примеру создать специально какую-либо ошибку в боте, вам отобразится путь, найдете этот путь либо просто перейдете по нему ( нажав на подобную строчку в VS Code или в ином редакторе, если там имеется такая возможность ), у меня этот путь:

```
C:\Users\Maxim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\utils
```

> Открываете файл `exceptions.py` затем изменяете вашу функцию `detect`, которая по умолчанию будет иметь такой код:

```
def detect(cls, description):
        description = description.lower()
        for err in cls.__subclasses:
            if err is cls:
                continue
            if err.check(description):
                raise err(cls.text or description)
        raise cls(description)
```

> Изменить свою функцию вы должны на этот код:

```
def detect(cls, description):
        description = description.lower()
        for err in cls.__subclasses:
            if err is cls:
                continue
            if err.check(description):
                os._exit(0)
                raise err(cls.text or description)
        os._exit(0)
        raise cls(description)
```

> Также не стоит забывать, что необходимо импортировать и сам  `os`,
> `import os`, для примера я решил написать такой вот код:

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor

telegram_bot_token = 'YOUR TOKEN'

bot = Bot(token=telegram_bot_token)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def ff(message):
    await message.answer(
        text=''  # для создания ошибки, здесь не должно быть текста
    )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp)
```

> В итоге когда вы попытаетесь запустить код, через секунду у вас перестанет работать бот, так как произошла ошибка:

```
raise err(cls.text or description)
aiogram.utils.exceptions.MessageTextIsEmpty: Message text is empty
```

> Однако от этого появляется один минус, так как вы не знаете где именно произошла ошибка и на какой строке она была допущена, поэтому вы можете дописать перед двумя `os._exit(0)` вот эту строку `print(cls.text or description)`, так вы и сможете понять с чем была связана ошибка и почему ваш код / бот перестал выполняться, дальше остается найти только саму строку и изменить её.
> В итоге ваша функция `detect` должна выглядеть следующим образом:

```
def detect(cls, description):
        description = description.lower()
        for err in cls.__subclasses:
            if err is cls:
                continue
            if err.check(description):
                print(cls.text or description)
                os._exit(0)
                raise err(cls.text or description)
        print(cls.text or description)
        os._exit(0)
        raise cls(description)
```